# sql value or column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I work on SQL server 2012, i have a value x and a column y contain some values (y1, y2, ..., yn)

i want to do bitwise or between x and y column

i perform

```
SELECT x | y
FROM someTable
```

which returns `x | y1`

can someone tell me how to do it please

Comment: "some values"? You have multiple values in a single field? That means it's a text field, and you can't do bitwise operations on it. bitwise only applies to numeric fields (e.g. ints). Storing multiple values in a single field is also almost always a sign of a bad design. ESPECIALLY if you need to start accessing individual sub-values in that field. Normalize your table, and your problem goes away.

Comment: Your query is correct for a bitwise `or`.

Comment: @MarcB what i meant that y is column not single value

Comment: so show EXACTLY what this "not single value" is. if it's something like `42 | '1,2,3'`, then that's exactly what I said - you cannot take the bitwise `or` of a string.

Comment: it's like 42 | 1 | 2 | 3 | ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create function getBitwiseOr(@data int, @k int)
returns int
as
begin
declare @consolidated int;
set @consolidated = @k
return @consolidated|@data
end
go


declare @x int, @k int;
SET @x=inputValue;
SET @k = 0;

select @k = dbo.getBitwiseOr((@x|Yvalue),@k) from HassanData
PRINT @k //this is the consolidated value
```

Comment: it returned a table of @x | y1, @x | y2, ...

how can i combine the result into single value?

Comment: you want consolidated bitwise or for all rows?

Comment: what do you mean by 'result into single value' ?